# Should I send HR a gift for Christmas?

Tags: human-resources, gifts

Is it a good idea to send a gift to the HR hiring manager as a thank you/Christmas gift after I have been accepted into a job?

The HR manager has certainly gone out of her way to assist me, answering my questions etc.

Thanks

edit: Chocolate and Card?

Comment: That's what the employee handbook is for. Read it - in particular, the section on gifts that employees may receive - and act accordingly. If still in doubt, ask HR not us. Voting to close because you are asking a question whose answer is company-policy specific.

Comment: Instead of trying to close the question (when it's a pretty valid question and can be applied in many situations with many employees) and instead of being a 'mini mod'  my question also mentioned that I had just been accepted into a job.  No employee handbook here.

Comment: Gifts that apply in terms of bribery/compliance are usually only considered when they're over a certain value.  I'm pretty sure that a card and a box of chocolates can be seen as an issue here.  On the other hand, the HR manager was only doing her job so probably isn't expecting a gift.

Comment: With all due respect, the HR manager was just doing her job. From your description, it sounds like she did her job exceptionally well, but that's about it. Giving people gifts for doing their job might offend some people, even if you meant it well.

Comment: That aside, you might want to pick a less confrontational attitude in general. Vietnhi has 20k+ reputation on this site, which gives him "trusted user" privileges, which means a whole lot more than a "mini mod" (whatever that means).

Answer (score 10):

Gifts are always tricky and may be seen as bribery. HR may not be allowed to accept it.

If you want to thank the hiring manager, send a nice card and no gift.

Comment: how about a box of chocolates and a card?  Do you think this is OK?

Comment: Honestly, just send a card. I appreciate that you think it's a harmless gesture, but it could cause issues around bribery. I remember a previous place had an xmas raffle of all the gifts anyone received, and it included daft things like chocolates/mouse mats. A card will suffice in this situation.

Comment: You could send it anonymous (even list the sender's name as John Doe).

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Honestly, that sounds even more fishy rather then less.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Would you eat something that came as an "anonymous gift"? If you want to thank somebody, send a thank-you card. Perfectly normal.

Comment: Sometimes I really don't understand this website... I replied to an answer and now my reply is being treated as an answer on its own.

Comment: @Stephan It doesn't sound like your comment is being treated as an answer. Your commented on someone's answer, and that person replied to your comment. That's all that has happened here, it is not clear why you have a different impression.

Answer (score 1):

I would urge you not do this ( no gift ), just stop by their office and say thanks.

> 1. Do I have to give a gift to my boss?
>
> You absolutely do not need to give a gift to your boss – and what’s
>   more, you shouldn’t.
>
> There’s very clear etiquette on this, which says that gifts in a
>   workplace should flow downward, not upward. That means gifts from
>   bosses to employees are fine, but employees should not be expected to
>   give gifts to those above them.
>
> This rule is understandable when you think about the power dynamics in
>   the boss-employee relationship. People shouldn’t feel obligated to
>   purchase gifts for someone with power over their livelihood, and
>   managers should never benefit from the power dynamic in that way.

Take a look at this for more information:  [US News](http://money.usnews.com/money/blogs/outside-voices-careers/2014/12/22/5-questions-about-office-gift-giving-answered)

Answer (score 0):

Most companies have rules about accepting gift. Where I work, I personally, or some person in HR, would not be allowed to accept a gift given to one person. Usually there are rules how such gifts are to be handled. For example a box of chocolates could be put up in the kitchen where everyone can take a piece. Other things could be put into a free tombola where everyone has a chance to win them. And other things might not be accepted at all.